# how to create a download files from the interactive cd

Tags: flash, interactive, cd

I have a college assignment, I had to create a function to download a file, but I put file in a directory on the interactive cd that I created using flash abode. how do I make this work?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's available AIR. you must using a [`File`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) Class.

refer a following code.

```
var dir:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath("MyDirectory"); 
dir.createDirectory();
```

More Information: [File Tutorial](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d8e.html)